# Android column '_id' does not exists

Tags: android, cursor

Previously I selected everything by putting a null, but i get an error complaining that it has too many rows, so I'm trying to get a projection of the display name, contact id and phone number but getting the following error:
"column '_id' does not exist"

Here's the code:

```
final String[] projection = { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID };

    Cursor cur = cr.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection,
            "LENGTH(" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
                    + ") >= 8 ) GROUP BY ("
                    + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, null,
            sortOrder);
```

But the error points to this line in my customadapter

```
super(context, layout, c, from, to);
```

Need help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`BaseColumns._ID`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html#_ID) to your projection array.

Answer (score 1):

android needs the _id column, so include your column with private key in your query.

you can rename the result column with something like this:

"select PRIMARYKEYCOLUMN as _id,BLA,BLUBB from TABLE"

Answer (score 0):

See your query. You may write column_id in place of contact_id by mistake else it will not show this type error..